# Linux asm x86_64 file create (__NR_creat 85), no file created

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

All, I am having difficulty with x86_64 assembly `file create`. The file create on x86 works fine. For example, on x86, a call to (`__NR_creat 8`) with mode `0420` results in creation of a file with octal permissions of `0644 octal -rw-r--r--` file permissions:

```
mov     eax, 8              ; system call number (sys_creat)
mov     ebx, [fnbuf]        ; set ebx to filename
mov     ecx, 0420           ; 644 octal -rw-r--r--
int     0x80                ; call kernel
```

While the syscall number in `asm-x86/unistd_64.h` changes to `85` and the kernel calling convention on x86_64 chases to ( `%rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %r10, %r8 and %r9` ) [**x86_64 ABI (A.2.1 Calling Convention)**](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), I would expect file create to work the same on x86_64. Making the code changes, the call would become:

```
mov     rax, 85             ; __NR_creat x86_64 syscall
mov     rdi, [ofname]       ; filename in rdi
mov     rsi, 0420           ; 644 octal -rw-r--r--
syscall                     ; call kernel
```

However, no file is created. Are there additional differences between x86 and x86_64 that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. I have been through every reference I can find on the issue and I cannot find any additional information on x86_64 sys_creat differences. I have a minimum verifiable example available here: [**filecreat_64.asm**](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/stack/asm/filecreate_64.asm). The `nasm` compile and link is:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o filecreat_64.o filecreat_64.asm
ld  -o filecreat_64 filecreat_64.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mov rdi, ofname` (ie. no brackets) since you have to pass the address of the filename. Incidentally, that should have been the same in 32 bit too.

PS: learn to use a debugger and `strace`.

Comment: Thank you. I used everything except `strace`. I used `gdb` to decompile a short `fopen` example, but didn't run the asm file. I had used the x86 and for some unexplained reason, it worked. Thanks again. It was a forrest for the trees issue I would have looked at for hours more...